# Query/Code working on NexusDB but not on Firebird Embedded

Tags: delphi

This query/code,if I just take out the DataModule stuff, works on
NexusDB.With Firebird embedded using FireDac it does not.
So either I am not doing something right in code or ...

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
DataModule2.FDQuery4.Active:=false;
DataModule2.FDQuery4.SQL.Clear;
DataModule2.FDQuery4.SQL.Add('select LOC_ID,USER,PASSWORD from USERS where USER='+QuotedStr(cxlookupcombobox1.Text)+' and GESLO ='+QuotedStr(cxTextEdit1.Text));
DataModule2.FDQuery4.Open;
if DataModule2.FDQuery4.FieldByName('PASSWORD').AsString<>''
then  begin
if DataModule2.FDQuery4.FieldByName('LOC_ID').asString = '13' 
then  begin
Form3.Show;
Form1.Hide;
end;
if DataModule2.FDQuery4.FieldByName('LOC_ID').asString = '15' 
then  begin
Form4.Show;
Form1.Hide;
end;
end else begin
cxTextedit1.Text := '';
showmessage('Wrong password !');
end;
end;
```

Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong ? 
Edit1 :Second part of the code (Form4.Show;) wont execute
Edit2 : Tried this way too :

```
....
if DataModule2.FDQuery4.FieldByName('PASSWORD').AsString<>''
then
case  DataModule2.FDQuery4.FieldByName('LOC_ID').Value of
13: begin
Form3.Show;
Form1.Hide;
end;
15 : begin
Form4.Show;
Form1.Hide;
end;
end else begin
cxTextedit1.Text := '';
showmessage('Wrong password !');
end;
end;
```

Second part (showing form 4 still wont work) ...

Comment: Well, you're using string concatenation instead of parameterized queries, to start. But you haven't explained what "not working" means, and if we don't know what you mean by "not working" we can't offer suggestions on how to make it work. What **specifically** is the problem with the code you've posted?

Comment: Second part of the code (Form4.Show;) wont execute.

Comment: So what does the debugger tell you when you step through that code (which we can't do for you)? What are the values in the fields (which we can't see either)? Those things are information that only you have, and only you can investigate; we can't read your screen or work your keyboard or mouse from where we sit. It might be easier to tell what's happening if you made some effort to format your code so that it was readable, and where the execution path was easy to see.

Comment: 'LOC_ID' is integer type in the database...(numbers)...Debugger tels me nothing. If the first part executes (showing form3) it should mean that its not a field problem. Why then is second part not exectuting?

Comment: Debug your program in a simple way: right after you open your query: `a := FDQuery4.FieldByName('PASSWORD').AsString`; `b := FieldByName('LOC_ID').AsString`; And use `ShowMessage` to display `a, b`. Are the tables **data** in sync? (NexusDB/Firebird)

Comment: I have nearly the same project using SQLite and UNIDac. Everything works Ok

Comment: But everything does NOT work OK on NexusDB, and you need to debug the code and examine the field values to determine why. *We cannot do that for you*. It's impossible that the debugger "tells you nothing"; it tells you what conditions exist (or fail to exist) that makes your code not execute as you want. You need to use it.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but this particular code works on nexusdb.It works on SQLite and it does with Absolute database too.Unfortunately debugger tells me nothing regarding this code's execution. Zero....Nada... Queries work in sync. I have tested this additionally with a label (to see if loc_id value gets changed at all). It does. So I am inclined to thing there might be a bug in these components when using Firebird embedded. Firedac with SQLite executes this code without a problem. On Firebird .... somehow.... it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the  flaw in my query. FDQuery4 just selects the required records once.Records are frozen. I should have checked the FDQuery3

```
....
if DataModule2.FDQuery4.FieldByName('password').AsString<>''
then begin
if DataModule2.FDQuery3.FieldByName('lok_ic').AsString = '13' 
then
Form3.Show;
Form1.Hide;
if DataModule2.FDQuery3.FieldByName('loc_id').AsString = '15' 
then
Form4.Show;
Form1.Hide;
if  DataModule2.FDQuery3.FieldByName('loc_id').AsString = '6'
then
Form5.Show;
Form1.Hide;
end else  begin
cxTextedit1.Text := '';
showmessage('wrong password !');
end;
end;
```

Silly me.... Thank you all ....